# Is it possible to write a function of the type `Monad m => t Identity a -> t m a` for every monad transformer `t`?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Suppose we have the following type class.

```hs
class MonadTrans t => MonadLower t where
    lower :: Monad m => t Identity a -> t m a
```

As a trivial example, we can implement an instance of `MonadLower` for `MaybeT` as follows.

```hs
instance MonadLower MaybeT where
    lower (MaybeT (Identity maybe)) = MaybeT (return maybe)
```

However, I can't figure out how to implement an instance of `MonadLower` for `ContT r`.

```hs
instance MonadLower (ContT r) where
    lower (ContT f) = ContT $ \k -> ???
```

Is it even possible to create an instance of `MonadLower t` for every `MonadTrans t`?

If not, which monad transformers (beside `ContT r`) can't have `MonadLower` instances?

---

**Edit:** [Edward Kmett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34707/edward-kmett) has defined a similar type class called [`MonadHoist`](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/106xwf/the_monadtrans_class_is_missing_a_method/).

```
class MonadHoist t where
    hoist :: (Monad m, Monad n) => (forall a. m a -> n a) -> t m a -> t n a
```

It turns out that `lower = hoist (return . runIdentity)`.

Comment: Is `lower` just `fmap (pure . runIdentity)`? What am I missing here?

Comment: @amalloy `ContT r Identity a` is `(a -> Identity r) -> Identity r`. Hence, `fmap` wouldn't work.

Comment: @amalloy It turns out that `lower` is `hoist (pure . runIdentity)`, where `hoist` is a function defined by [Edward Kmett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34707/edward-kmett) in his [`MonadHoist`](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/106xwf/the_monadtrans_class_is_missing_a_method/) class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Mauro](https://www.blogger.com/profile/12330175633010569183) we can't define a `MonadHoist` instance for `ContT`<sup>[[1](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/09/the-monadtrans-class-is-missing-method.html?showComment=1348709161563#c8094017856997636775)]</sup>.

> What Edward is proposing is to have a class of *functorial* monad transformers (transformers which are endofunctors in the category Mon(C) of monads over a category C and monad morphisms)
>
> **Note that some transformers, like the continuation monad transformer, are not functorial.**